# How to call url in jquery from anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jplayer

I'm working on a web application, Here look at below this jquery codes:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var myPlaylist = new jPlayerPlaylist({
        jPlayer: "#jplayer_N",
        cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_N"
    }, [
      {
          title: "<Here is song title>",
          artist: "<here is artist>",
          mp3: "Here is song URL", //Here i want to call URL from anchor tag..
          poster: "images/m0.jpg"
      }
    ], {
        playlistOptions: {
            enableRemoveControls: true,
             ................
             ................
```

Now here is my html code, i want to play this music:

```
<a href="Music/Linkin_park.mp3">Play Linkin park</a>

<a href="Music/Linkin_park2.mp3">Play Linkin park2</a>

<a href="Music/Linkin_park3.mp3">Play Linkin park3</a>
```

What should i use in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the following ?

```
<a id="lp1" href="Music/Linkin_park.mp3">Play Linkin park</a>
<a id="lp2" href="Music/Linkin_park2.mp3">Play Linkin park2</a>
<a id="lp3" href="Music/Linkin_park3.mp3">Play Linkin park3</a>
```

And then calling `$("#lp1").click();` with a onClick() method for playing each song.

---

Or maybe you looked for something like this :

```
var songtoplay = $("#lp1").attr("href");

$(document).ready(function () {

var myPlaylist = new jPlayerPlaylist({
    jPlayer: "#jplayer_N",
    cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_N"
}, [
  {
      title: "<Here is song title>",
      artist: "<here is artist>",
      mp3: songtoplay,
      poster: "images/m0.jpg"
  }
], {
    playlistOptions: {
        enableRemoveControls: true,
         ................
         ................
```

Comment: You just turned the situation in other way.. rather i would prefer to copy URL directly into jquery code. But suppose Let if i've three anchor tag in browser and my wish to play these all three songs along. What will you do in that case?

Comment: Can you elaoborate more in details..?

Answer (score 0):

You can get an url with the following code `$("#identifier").attr("href");`

Since I don't know the structure of your application I suggest you do a `foreach` through all the `a` elements

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
$( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
event.preventDefault();
alert($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Hope this be of some help

Happy Learning :)